# Roots of equation $x^3-x-1=0$

Tags: polynomials, cubics

If 
  
    α
    ,
    β
    ,
    γ

are the roots of equation $x^3 -x -1 =0$
then

$$ \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}  + \frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta} + \frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma} $$

My attempt is in the attachment
[image: My attempt]

I got answer $=0$ but in book answer is given as $-7$ . Where I do mistake by solving the question ?

Comment: Componendo-dividendo is not applied correctly. Verify that this step is incorrect by expanding both sides.

Comment: So how we apply Componendo-dividendo  in that step?

Comment: just a formatting tip: \alpha, \beta and \gamma gives the corresponding greek letters when in a math enviroment, that is surrounded by sollar signs ;)

Comment: @vinyl thanks for this knowledge

Comment: Solving for $x$ from $t=(1+x)/(1-x)$ gives $x=(t-1)/(t+1)$. Therefore $(1+\alpha)/(1-\alpha)$ and friends are zeros of 
$$
\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^3-\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)-1=\frac{-x^3-7x^2+x-1}{(1+x)^3}=0.$$

Comment: We don't apply CD and instead focus on the polynomial whose roots are the three quantities whose sum you are looking for. Now use Jyrki's hint to find this polynomial. Since you know the answer the polynomial should be clear from Jyrki's working

Comment: @jaykri can We solve this question without using transformation of equation concept ?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Okk I don't use picture any more.

Comment: Please don't be discouraged by [using pictures in questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3112790/290189).  They are nice ways to provide illustrations to questions/answers.  However, they are *not* a substitute to typing text/math.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see
e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0/2157645#2157645 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203364/solve-the-following-equation-x3-3x-sqrtx2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint...write $$y=\frac{1+x}{1-x}\implies x=\frac{y-1}{y+1}$$ and substitute into the polynomial. Simplify the polynomial in $y$ and find the sum of the roots.

Alternatively,$$\Sigma\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=-3+2\Sigma\frac{1}{1-\alpha}$$
$$=-3+2\frac{3+\Sigma\alpha\beta-2\Sigma\alpha}{1-\Sigma\alpha+\Sigma\alpha\beta-\alpha\beta\gamma}$$
$$=-3+2\frac{3-1-0}{1-0-1-1}=-7$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=2\sum\frac{1}{1-\alpha}-3\cdots (1)$$

Where $$\sum\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}+\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}+\frac{1-\gamma}{1-\gamma}.$$

Now adding $1$ in each term and

subtracting $-3$,We get equation no $(1)$

Now $$x^3-x-1=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$$

Taking $\ln$ and Differentiate both side and put $x=1$

$$\frac{3(1)^2-1}{(1)^3-(1)-1}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}+\frac{1}{1-\beta}+\frac{1}{1-\gamma}$$

So we get  $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{1-\alpha}=-2$

put into $(1)$, we have $$\displaystyle \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=-4-3=-7.$$

Comment: Can you explain the first step..

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\sum\bigg(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}+1\bigg)-3=2\sum\frac{1}{1-\alpha}-3$

Comment: Sir , why you have added 1 then also subtracted 3 ??

Comment: because  $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}=\bigg(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}+1\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}+1\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1+\gamma}{1-\gamma}+1\bigg)-3$